# 000webhost mysql connection error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to my database using the following code:

```
<?php
            $mysql_host = "mysql*.000webhost.com";
            $mysql_database = "a******_account";
            $mysql_user = "a******_admin";
            $mysql_password = "******";

            // Create connection 
            $con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

            // Check connection 
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
            { 
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
            };
        ?>
```

Does anyone know what is going on?
The error messages are:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'a******_admin'@'0.0.0.0' (using password: YES) in /home/a3996154/public_html/index.php on line 18

and

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'a******_admin'@'0.0.0.0' (using password: YES)

Comment: Looks like it can't find your host ip address - make sure your domain name is correct - sometimes that is not same as your web hosting site

Comment: It's the hosting address given in the mysql tab of the cpanel

Comment: @IvanRoss So finally did you set the $mysql_host = "mysql*.000webhost.com"; or $mysql_host = "127.0.0.1";?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably: Your auth is wrong, or that user doesn't have permission to access to that database.

Comment: It's the account that you set the database up using

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it took a day for the database to respond, today it is up and running. Excuse me for any time I wasted.